# I'm starting to learn Spring Boot and I run into this error

Tags: spring

I'm starting to learn Spring Boot and I run into this error!

```
class com.microsoft.java.debug.core.adapter.handler.LaunchUtils (in unnamed module @0x30b55c6f) cannot access class sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.security.action to unnamed module @0x30b55c6f
```

[image]

I followed steps in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uq4GjRF_860

Comment: Copy the error text and paste it here.

Comment: class com.microsoft.java.debug.core.adapter.handler.LaunchUtils (in unnamed module @0x30b55c6f) cannot access class sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.security.action to unnamed module @0x30b55c6f

Comment: I get the same error when trying to include javax.mail-api or com.google.crypto.tink

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error in VSCode. Not sure the solution, but using JetBrains IntelliJ with the same setup worked for me.

Comment: Yeah I switched to IntelliJ and all seems to work for now.

Answer (score 1):

I have got this issue when I created project with Java 16 where my JAVA_HOME was pointing to 1.8. From the error message it seemed to me, that the issue is with java modules which got introduced from Java 9. Even after pointing JAVA_HOME to 16 the error did not get resolved. So I have tried the last option of installing new VS code and uninstalled the old one. Then the issue got resolved and I was able to run the spring boot app.